# Meaning of $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) = \infty$

Tags: general-topology, limits, definition

> Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^m, f:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Explain what means $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \infty$

Sorry if the question is rather simple, unfortunatelly I couldn't find an answer on my textbooks.

How can I define what means to a vector go to infinity? Does it mean all of it's coordinates go to infinity or that $|x|$ tends to infinity?

for $n=1$ I have that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) = \infty$ means that $\forall M>0$ exists $H>0$ such that $\forall x>H \implies f(x)>M$.

but how can I match this for $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$? If I use the norm I could have each coordinate of x or f(x) going to $-\infty$ and still $|x|>H$ and $|f(x)|>M$

The definition would be with $H \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $M \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and the inequalities would be $x_i>h_i \forall i=1,...,m \implies f(x)_j>m_j\ \forall j=1,...,n$ ?

Comment: Did you look in the book's index under "limit" and see what is said when the notation is introduced?

Comment: I think there's little doubt that $f(x)=(x,x)\to\infty$ as $x\to \infty$, for any reasonable definition of $\to\infty$ in the plane. However, what about $(x,-x)$ or $(x,3)$? If your book doesn't have an explicit definition, then this is going to be difficult to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talking about vectors, there's no $\pm\infty$ in general (unless you talk about a certain coordinate), just $\infty$. And the limit is usually defined with the correspondent norm, i. e., $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ means that $\forall N>0$ exists $M>0$ such that if $||x||>M$ then $||f(x)||>N$.

Comment: Usually I'd expect to see it written $\lim_{x\to\infty}\lVert f(x)\rVert=\infty.$ It takes so little extra effort to make one's intended meaning perfectly clear in such cases; why not do it?

Comment: I guess that it's easier to write just $f(x)$. Furthermore, you should also write $||x||\to\infty$ in that case. I find the usual way clear because the notion of infinity in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is different than in $\mathbb{R}$, the same way than the derivative behaves different in higher dimensions.

Comment: Good point about $||x||\to\infty,$ and I suppose you're right about the rest as well. If this showed up in a textbook I'd expect the notation to have been defined somewhere earlier in the same book.

Answer (score 2):

When you have $\infty$ in any kind of limit notation on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n \neq 1$, you must expect (if not told otherwise) to be dealing with the [one-point compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension), for which the notation is clear and the limit is the usual topological limit:

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty^m}f(x)=\infty^n$

(where the $m,n$ are there for the sake of explicity), which means precisely that for every neighbourhood $V$ of $\infty^n$, there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $\infty^m$ such that $f$ takes $U\backslash \{\infty^m\}$ inside $V$. Since neighbourhoods of $\infty$ are complements of compact sets (by definition), one can show that this is equivalent to saying that for every $M>0$, there exists $K>0$ such that if $\Vert {x}\Vert >K$, then $\Vert f(x)\Vert>M$.

If $n=1$ or $m=1$, the notation can be a bit confusing with the also standard two-point compactification $[-\infty,+\infty]$. Some people prefer to explicitly put a sign in front of $\infty$ (denoting thus by $+\infty,-\infty$) if they are dealing with the two-point compactification, in order to implicitly tell that they are not dealing with the one-point compactification.